# Javascript Stop Working when converting website to Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, validation

I finished creating http://www.cobalt-chromium-toxicity.com/ as a static html/css website, and am trying to convert it to Wordpress. I am losing my validation functionality on the form as well as the hide/show video functionality at the bottom.

In the Wordpress version of the [website](http://www.idiodesignstudio.com/websites/cobalt/) I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.validate.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/videos.js">
</script>
```

In the header.php right above

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

Comment: I notice you've tagged this with [tag:java] as well as [tag:javascript]. But please tell us, where does Java fit into your problem?

Comment: Have you checked that jquery.js has been called?

Comment: Have you checked the error-output in your browsers console?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't see java listed as one of my tags, but sorry if that confused you. 

IanBrindley I have the following in my functions.php, I was under the impression that would activate jquery, but am relatively new to this:

 if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
       function my_jquery_enqueue() {
       wp_deregister_script('jquery');
       wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }


Thanks again for the help

Comment: @user1981932: that's because someone else has edited your post and has since removed it, but when you initially posted your question the tag was there. Please be careful with tagging since Java and JavaScript are completely different animals. Also please don't post code in comments as it is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I think `"echo get_template_directory_uri();"` instead of `"bloginfo('template_directory');"` will work for you.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are missing the **echo** in the php code, like:

```
<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

Comment: bloginfo() automatically prints